# Prevent audio lags on heavy cpu load

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm creating an audio player with WPF and NAudio in C#.
Whenever the performance of my computer is low, the audio starts to lag extremely which sounds aweful. I noticed that this does not seem to be the case for similar applications like Spotify or Windows Media Player.

How can I increase the performance of the audio thread? Is there a way to give it priority before other threads?

Edit: Code

```
WavePlayer = new WaveOut();
source = new AudioFileReader(Filepath)
WavePlayer.Init(source);
WavePlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Can you provide any of the source code?

Comment: I added the relevant code to my question, but there is not really much to show, though...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the performance of my computer is low"? Is your whole PC pretty much maxed out for the CPU? Or is it just your application that runs at around 100% CPU usage? Also is your `WavePlayer` running in a separate thread, or are you running it in the main thread?

Comment: @rene The given code is run in an wpf event callback function

Comment: @bassfader The machine I'm currently experiencing this issue on generally has a pretty bad performance as it is a approx. 8 year old notebook, but I guess it should be fast enough to play a bit of music. Currently it is running on 39% CPU load and 80% RAM usage

Comment: What is a _wpf event callback function_? In C#, it's all about methods, not functions. Did you mean an event handler? Which event exactly?

Comment: Ok, so this sounds to me like you're running the `WavePlayer` in the main / the UI thread. And it seems like the thread is pretty much maxed out (since most likely most other stuff is handled in that very same main / UI thread too). Have you tried moving the `WavePlayer` to a separate thread (for example using a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx))?

Comment: You are using the waveout driver. Did you give WASPI or ASIO a chance? See https://mark-dot-net.blogspot.de/2011/05/naudio-audio-output-devices.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, in a WinForms / WPF app, `WaveOut` will use the UI thread to fill the audio buffers. If you use `WaveOutEvent` instead, you'll get a background thread doing that work for you. `WasapiOut` and `DirectSoundOut` also work this way.

Remember that if you can't fill buffers in a timely fashion you will get stuttering/drop outs in audio. So if switching driver model doesn't work for you, you might need to optimise your audio code, or increase the buffer durations.